# Form submit triggers unwanted download

Tags: html, forms, download, upload

This is a weird problem ... I have a html form that should check the inputs, process a upload and send two mails on submit. But instead when i submitting it its downloads a file named `Download` without any file extension.

This file has contents like this:

```
1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0003 258f 314f c330
1085 77ff 8aa3 3b71 e86c 79a0 09a2 a2d0
0c66 6074 9313 b1e4 d8e6 7c01 f9df e3a4
d3e9 e9d3 f7f4 4e3d 74d7 93f9 1a7a 7835
ef17 183e 9f2f e713 1c1e a53c f7e6 45ca
...
```

On my local machine this doesn't happen so probably it has something to do with the hoster? Its hosted on a strato shared hosting.

Also it is using wordpress. I know that there can be some errors if u are using specific input names but that shouldn't be a problem here.

Does this looks similar to anyone? I have no clue whats the problem ...

Comment: Without code we cannot even guess. Show the form and other relevant code in [mcve]

Comment: Have a look at https://lerch-genuss.de/karriere/#karriere. I think if i am going to use this in a other enviroment it probably works ...

Comment: Not a clue - perhaps the server sends some headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's the thing. Strato has some kind of security-mechanism that kills these requests. Its called Server-Side-Security or something like that.

Why this is exactly happening is unclear ... It only appears when a e-mail is entered in some of these fields. So it checks the POST requests in some way and decides if there are right or not.

Looks to me like a very poor mechanism ... you can deactivate that in the hosting-administration under Your package > Security > ServerSide Security.

This seems to be a pretty strato specific problem so i don't know if this thread is subject to delete.